# Multithreading: Same two object is entering into synchronized block

Tags: multithreading, locking, synchronized

May be my header would not be correct.

I have started java multithread concept with programming. since i have read inside synchronized block only one thread will inter on a particular object lock. But i have confused after looking the output of this program.
package com.example.classandobjectlevellock;

class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    Object ob = new Object();

```
public void run() {

    synchronized (this) {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Is waitng");
        try {
            this.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

}

public class ClassAndObjectLevelLock {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    MyThread task1 =  new MyThread();
    MyThread task2 =  new MyThread();

    Thread t1 = new Thread(task1,"Thread1");
    Thread t2 = new Thread(task1,"Thread2");

    Thread t3 = new Thread(task2,"Thread3");

    t1.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    t2.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    t3.start();

}
```

}
 Output: 
Thread1 Is waitng
Thread2 Is waitng
Thread3 Is waitng

If i am not wrong, Thread-1 and thread-3 is entering into synchronized method because it having two different target object. But why Thread-2 is entering into Synchronized block?

Please help me for understanding of this .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please suggest me some link for programming of multithreaded question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `wait()` causes the lock to be released.

Per [the `wait()` Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()):

> Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the
>   `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object. In
>   other words, this method behaves exactly as if it simply performs the
>   call `wait(0)`.
>
> The current thread must own this object's monitor. **The thread
>   releases ownership of this monitor** and waits until another thread
>   notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either
>   through a call to the `notify` method or the `notifyAll` method. The
>   thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and
>   resumes execution.